# dragging and dropping 1gg of files into a 2gg flashdrive

Tags: windows-vista, sp2

I have tried dragging and dropping 642 pictures (less than 1gg) into a 2gg flashdrive.  It stops at picture 511.  If I use copy and paste there is no problem.  It completes that task.
Is there a setting I can change in the computer to allow the task to work in drag and drop?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put the pictures into a subdirectory, or reformat the drive to FAT32.

It sounds like your flash drive is formatted with FAT16 ("FAT"), which would be surprising but would account for a limit on the number of files in the root directory. FAT32 doesn't have that limitation and should be supported on all operating systems new enough to also recognize USB devices.

Comment: +1. 512 is a FAT16 telltale; although FAT16 can be configured to allow more than 512 root entires, there's no reason not to use a better filesystem such as FAT32 on a flash drive.